# Length Property of a column definition not recognized

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Warning: I am still **very** new to NHibernate and Fluent!

I have a mapping like this:

```
Map(x => x.Category).Column("CATEGORY")
                    .CustomType("String")
                    .Access.Property()
                    .Generated.Never()
                    .CustomSqlType("nvarchar(250)")  // <----
                    .Not.Nullable()
                    .Length(250);                    // <----
```

I need to define *.CustomSqlType("nvarchar****(250)***") to get a column with a width of 250 when I let NH create the schema for me.  If I omit the "(250)" a column with a width of 1 is created. I am wondering what the ".Length(250)" setting is good for.

I also have trouble to find documentation about the ".Generated.Never()" setting.  What does it mean?

For those of you that might ask: where did he get tat mapping code from?  I used a tool to generate it for a starter and I am happy that it works more or less.  Now I try to understand it...

Can someone please help out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NH uses `.Length(250);` to determine the length of a string property in the database (normally *nvarchar*). AFAIK it is ignored completely when you specify your own customsqltype